# Period (.) in dataset field name - Cannot bind to repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dataset that i am binding to a repeater. The `GetXML()` of the dataset looks like this:

```
<NewDataSet>
 <Table1>
   <Company.Date>03/22/2009</Company.Date>
  </Table1>
</NewDataSet>
```

The aspx looks like this:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Company.Date")%>
```

When I bind it, I get the error:

```
System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Company'.
```

It doesn't seem to like the period. Is there a way to fix this without changing the naming convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Object, String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.databinder.getpropertyvalue.aspx), it does not evalulate the string but uses it in its exact form to get the value.

[Source](http://www.victorchen.info/period-or-dot-in-column-name-error-in-c/)